# Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined, trying to parse JSON

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to find the output of the following code:

```
 <html>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
            function request (){
                var URL = " http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1”;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: URL,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: “{}”,
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function(msg) {
                        var json = msg; //NOTE since we said we’re getting back jsonp, jQuery did the parsing for us!
                        document.getElementById("current").innerHTML=json.title;
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    document.getElementById("current").innerHTML = “Error fetching “ + URL;
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
        <button type="button" onclick="request()"></button>
        <div id="output"></div>
    </body>
<html>
```

I wrote the last parts, the button and the div. I was curious what the output of the parsed JSON would be, but I get an error when I try to run through it - that the function "request" isn't defined. I think it has something to do with the src, but I'm lead to believe that I need that there as I don't have Jquery natively. I tried looking around and all the others with this problem seem to be doing entirely different things. Is there something wrong with how I wrote this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `data: “{}”,` is totally wrong... Syntax Error!

Comment: For the record, I realize that the ID tags don't match up - that doesn't seem to have bearing on my current issue though.

Comment: I fixed your issue bro... Check the answer for explanation.

Comment: Regarding syntax, what's wrong with it? The ajax code itself was from a lecture last week, I just wanted to give it a test run. I assumed that part of the code to be correct.

Comment: Bro the quotes are stylized quotes... They aren't normal ones.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of errors:

1. Use an event listener.
2. Using same `<script>` for including and embedding.
3. Use ready event.
4. Using quoted JavaScript object.
5. Wrong quotes.
6. Mixing JavaScript and jQuery.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
      var URL = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";    // 1
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: URL,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {},    // 2
        // dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(msg) {
          var json = msg; //NOTE since we said we’re getting back jsonp, jQuery did the parsing for us!
          $("#output").html(json.title);  // 3
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          $("#output").html("Error fetching " + URL);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
<button type="button"></button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. Thanks. I guess part of it was just me not understanding how jquery interacts with things like the button. Appreciate the quick answer!